# Run executable from php script through ajax call doesn't work

Tags: wamp, user-permissions

I wrote a web-based app that run on (local) WAMP server on windows 7
That app launch an executable in background with script 'foo.php'.
This 'foo.php' can run in 2 mode:

1. Automatically launched by another php script (like a cron);
2. By user through ajax command;

When launched manually or in the first case, the executable work fine, but when launched from user (second case) it can't read some system folders (normally readable from all users (e.g. C:\ProgramData and C:\Program files\common files\system\ado).

I tried to change run mode (run as administrator) on my executable, Apache, PHP but nothing has changed.

Comment: You need to provide the running `user` account of PHP the appropriate permissions to the executable, or run PHP as a different user. This is why when you run it from a command line as your local administrator account it works, since PHP is being run as you, but not through Apache. In the Apache or PHP-FPM config it has its own user account it runs PHP as. To resolve the issue you can either add the Apache/PHP-FPM user to the desired directories, add the user to an appropriate group with permissions,  or create a scheduled task, with the desired credentials pointing to the executable.

Comment: It's important to note that the `run as administrator` setting in windows, is to FORCE elevation when the executable is run, requiring a non-administrator to provide credentials to continue execution. It does not permit the executable to run as administrator. In which case it is bad practice to allow other users to execute an application (Apache/PHP) running in administrator mode, as that would grant them complete control over your system/server.

Comment: Thanks.
I had assumed that the problem is on the permissions of the user used by apache / php, but I have not found any reference on where to trace the user is used and how to modify the default permissions

Comment: How can I run php as different user?

Comment: Change the `wamp/bin/Apache/conf/httpd.conf` setting for `User daemon` to another user. This will cause Apache and any module ie. `mod_php` it runs to be run as the specified user. You should create a dedicate user, and assign the user to an appropriate group.

Comment: Also for windows systems?